# Query last row from 2012 + all rows from 2013 + first row from 2014 using Rails(ActiveRecord) - Best Practice

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I finding best practice solution to fetch rows from database using this conditions:

Last row from year 2012
All rows from year 2013
and first row from 2014

Is this solvable by one query in Rails.

I have no idea how to do it by one query but only using 3 queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how you would do this in raw SQL?

Comment: Yes i can make 3 queries: (1.) SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE YEAR(dt) = 2012 ORDER BY dt LIMIT 1; (2.) SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE YEAR(dt) >= 2013 AND YEAR(dt) < 2014 ORDER BY dt; (3.) SELECT * FROM measurements WHERE YEAR(dt) = 2014 ORDER BY dt LIMIT 1; And then merge result together.

Comment: Technically it's one query if you use UNION.

Comment: Apparently, [UNION support was added recently](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/939).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it. I'm not saying it's the best or super optimized though, depends on your data and indexes.

```
@measurements = Measurement.find_by_sql( 
 %{select * from measurements 
   where date_part('year', date) = 2013
   or date = (select max(date) from rounds where date_part('year', date) = 2012)
   or date = (select min(date) from rounds where date_part('year', date) = 2014)
   order by date})
```

Edit: I see you're using sqlite, this works for Postgres but should be easily portable.

Comment: @jan-valiska Does this answer your question, if so mark it as an answer please, or the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me, only it was with `postgres` and `YEAR(dt)` was `date_part('year',dt)`. Plain and simple...

```
Measurement.where("YEAR(dt)=2013 or dt=? or dt=?",
    Measurement.where("YEAR(dt)=2012").maximum(:dt),
    Measurement.where("YEAR(dt)=2014").minimum(:dt))
```